# Grouping and finding mean in R dataframe

Tags: r, mean

I have a table like this:

| genderTime | Salary | Grade |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ftMale | 32000 | G |
| ptMale | 15500 | DP |
| ptMale | 37500 | H |
| ptFemale | 31500 | G |
| ftFemale | 37400 | H |
| ftMale | 36000 | G |
| ptFemale | 31000 | G |
| ptFemale | 16000 | DP |
| ptMale | 37000 | H |

I have the Grades as a factor where grades = DP, G, H

I need to create a table that gives me the **mean** salary by grade for full-time males (ftMale) and part-time males (ptMale) like so:

| Grade | Full-time Male | Part-time male |
| --- | --- | --- |
| DP | 0 | 15500 |
| G | 34000 | 0 |
| H | 0 | 37250 |

My dataset is a lot larger than this and there would be means for part time and full time in each grade. Any help would be much appreciated!
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Group by `Grade` and then summarize your data by getting the mean of `Salary` while making sure that you are subsetting to the relevant `ftMale/ptMale` values.

```
library(tidyverse)

df |>
  group_by(Grade) |>
  summarize(full_time_male = mean(Salary[genderTime == "ftMale"]),
            part_time_male = mean(Salary[genderTime == "ptMale"]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another dplyr approach:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(genderTime, Grade) %>% 
  summarise(Salary = mean(Salary, na.rm=TRUE)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = genderTime, values_from = Salary, values_fill = 0) %>% 
  select("Grade", "ftMale", "ptMale")

# A tibble: 3 × 3
  Grade ftMale ptMale
  <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1 H          0  37250
2 G      34000      0
3 DP         0  15500
```

Just another (slightly different) dplyr solution

```
df %>% 
  filter(genderTime %in% c("ftMale", "ptMale")) %>% 
  group_by(genderTime, Grade) %>% 
  summarise(Salary = mean(Salary, na.rm=TRUE)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = genderTime, values_from = Salary, values_fill = 0)
```

The same using full R base:

```
reshape(aggregate(Salary ~ genderTime + Grade, 
                  subset = genderTime %in% c("ftMale", "ptMale"), 
                  FUN=mean, 
                  data=df), 
        direction = "wide", 
        idvar = "Grade", 
        timevar = "genderTime")
```